# SemVer vulnerabilities issue with Vite+React JS

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, semantic-versioning, npm-vulnerabilities

I've created a new project to work on with **vite** & **react JS**.
Running the command `npm create vite@latest` works fine, and them I have to run `npm install`
this doesn't quite end well, because it says that there are 5 modern vulnerabilites.
and then running `npm audit` gives this report:

```
# npm audit report

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
No fix available
node_modules/semver
  @babel/core  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @babel/helper-compilation-targets
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/@babel/core
    @babel/helper-compilation-targets  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @babel/core
    Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
    node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets
    @vitejs/plugin-react  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @babel/core
    node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react
  eslint-plugin-react  7.19.0 || >=7.26.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/eslint-plugin-react

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

I tried `npm audit fix` and it did nothing, then tried `npm audit fix --force` and it fixes only one vulnerability, but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using

```
"overrides": { "semver": "^7.5.3" }
```

it needs to be added in the **Package.json** file. And then run:

```
npm audit fix
```

it fixes the vulnerabilies, although i don't really know if this doesn't cause issues when further developing

I want to thank *"vinnisch"* from github "https://github.com/vinnisch" as he gave the solution on this question "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25431#issuecomment-1609577821"